# How many different ways to place $m$ indistinguishable items in $N$ spaces (being able to contain at most one item each)?

Tags: combinatorics

At first I thought, "easy! When placing the first item, I have $N$ possibilities, and when placing the next I have $N-1$, and so on, until I only have one item left, at which point I have $N-(m-1)=N-m+1$ possibilities for placing it. So it should be $$\frac{N!}{(N-m)!},"$$
but I fear I have over counted it.

Is this the correct approach? If not, what is?

Thanks!

Comment: It appears likely that more than one item may be permitted in each space, in which your method would not be correct. This is a partitioning problem, but in which you must consider the empty partitions as well as the non-empty ones.  These are tricky.

Comment: @RobertFrost There is only room for one item in each space. Edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nearly correct, except that the order in which you place the objects does not matter. For each pattern of filled/unfilled boxes, there are $m!$ ways of ordering the placed objects, so your answer will be $m!$ times too big. Dividing your answer by this gives what we want: $$\frac{N!}{(N-m)!m!}$$ This is usually denoted $\binom{N}{m}$ and pronounced '$N$ choose $m$'.

Comment: Yep, I knew that... I feel dumb now :P Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea, but you have overcounted. Notice how you talked about the "first one" and etc. How do you know which one is first?

Looked at another way, say I place item 1 in bin $j$, and item 2 in bin $k$. If I swap them around, have I made a new arrangement? In the way you initially counted, you added one for the first scenario, and one for its reverse, when they aren't distinct. If you think about this some more to generalize to all $m$ objects, you'll see that you need to divide by the number of ways of rearranging the $m$ objects once they've been placed (or before placement begins - it's numerically equivalent).